# Custom validator to generated checkboxes in ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, angular-forms

I have a `html` code in which I iterate over an array:

```
<div class="container">
  <ol *ngFor="let g of guides">
    <button  type="button" class="form-control" (click)="open(g)" [class.not-confirmed]="!g.confirm" [class.confirmed]="g.confirm">{{g.description}}</button>
    <div [hidden]="!g.canOpen" style="text-align: center">
      <p>test</p>
      <label>Zapoznałem się</label>
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="g.confirm">
    </div>
  </ol>
  <button class="btn btn-default form-control" (click)="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

Is is possible to write a custom validator to check whether all checkboxes are ticked (checked) and then make last button 'save' available to click? I started writing some pieces of code as `reactive forms` but it's difficult to me:
1. How to deal with multiple checkboxes which will be generated based on array size?
2. How to add to each checkbox value as `ngModel` which will come from the backend entitled `g.confirm`?

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    confirmation: new FormControl()
  }, CustomValidator.checkAllCheckboxes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If g.confirm is boolean that should work fine.

NgModel will change the array that the data is pulled from, and then when you click save to call the save() function, you can check the array that created the checkboxes to see if all of the confirm properties are true and then either submit it, or show an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a listener on the form changes and keep an auxiliary array to follow the process. As soon as all are ticked, set the button disabled false. Something like the following:

**Typescript**

```
...
enabledButton: boolean;
auxiliary=[] //same size as the checkboxes number
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;
myForm: NgForm;
....
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((value: any) => {
         console.log("One of the checkbox was touched");
         // here check if the all values of the auxiliary array are true
         //if so:
         this.enableButton = true
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="enabledButton" ...>.....
```